# How do I display data in asp.net that has follows a specific pattern/ format?

Tags: asp.net, repeater, datalist, asp.net-controls

I have this table [image]

and what I want to is have something like this on the browser. [image]

The table has 8 rows and 3 columns

Here's my sql query: "SELECT q.QuestionID, q.QuestionText, q.GroupNo FROM question q ORDER BY GroupNo asc"
I have already stored the questions but I'm having a hard time printing it in this format.

Wherein after printing 4 questions it will then go to another cell and print 4 questions again and then once there are already 3 columns it will then create a new row and do the same step again.

[ In the database the 1st 4 questions are QuestionID1,2,3,4 and then the cell on it's right are 6,7,8,9 and so on....]

I want to display the questions in this pattern.

I'm stuck with this for almost two days already.... I tried looking for other solutions online but I wasn't able to find something that is quite similar with what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm trying to do it with either datalist or a repeater. If you could provide a solution that uses both it would be of really++ great help

Sir/Ma'am your answers would be of great help. Thank you++

Answer (score 1):

I think you should give up the existing controls like repeater or datalist.Just use your own code to implement this function.Maybe like this:

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
sb.append("...");
}
sb.append("...");
for(int i=4;i<8;i++)
{
sb.append("...");
}
```